# Getting chart pictures from tradingview

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, tradingview-api

Is there any way to use node.js or a backend service to get a picture of a chart from tradingview ? The tradingview API that is provided does not provide any options for this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Comment: I skimmed through their website and it looks like they offer a few libraries for presenting charts @ https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/ . It may be worth looking into and may have the API in mind given that both resources are from the same source.

Comment: can you please share the resource of which tradingview api or sdk that you are using..

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create backend services to serve serval endpoints.
2. Use UDF - It's an HTTP-based protocol that is designed to deliver data to the Charting Library in a simple and efficient way.

Services(APIs) endpoints which you need to create
some of them are:

1. **Data feed configuration data**
   URL - `/config`
2. **Symbol group request**
   URL - GET `/symbol_info?group=<group_name>`
3. **Symbol resolve**
   URL - GET `/symbols?symbol=<symbol>`

For candle/bar data you have to create:
URL - GET `/history?symbol=<ticker_name>&from=<unix_timestamp>&to=<unix_timestamp>&resolution=<resolution>`

Refer: https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/UDF

Comment: Do you know that is it possible to pass data to the chart? I mean I have my own symbols which I want to pass it through!

Answer (score 0):

Call getImage :

```
getImage = (e) => {
        if (this.TradingWidget) {
            this.setState({
                divStyle: {
                    width: 1440,
                    height: 600,
                    opacity: 0
                }
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.TradingWidget.postMessage.get("imageURL", {}, ((function (t) {
                    this.downloadImage(`https://s3.tradingview.com/snapshots/${t.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase()}/${t}.png`);
                }).bind(this)));
            }, 100)

        }
    }

    downloadImage = async (imageSrc) => {
        try {
            console.log("this.TradingWidget.iframe.style.width 3 :", this.TradingWidget.iframe.style.width)
            const image = await fetch(imageSrc);
            const imageBlog = await image.blob();
            const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog);
            this.props.getSnapShot(imageBlog, imageURL);
            this.setState({
                divStyle: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    opacity: 1
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            ErrorNotification("دریافت ادرس تصویر با خطا مواجه شد");
            this.props.setSnapShot(null)
        } finally {
        }

    }
```